# Teradata Equivalent to this SQL Server DATETIME code?

Tags: sql, date, teradata

Hi I am unfamiliar with SQL Server and need to translate this into usable Teradata SQL. Can anyone assist? Many Appreciations.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = CAST(DATEPART(MM, GETDATE())-1 AS VARCHAR) + '/01/' + 
    CAST(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)

SET @EndDate = EOMONTH(@StartDate)

--This will allow you to see the values without having to run a select query filter.
PRINT @StartDate
PRINT @EndDate

SELECT * 
FROM Product
WHERE DateCreated BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

To use variables in Teradata you need to write a Stored Procedure.

`@StartDate` is set to the first day of the previous month:

```
Cast(Trunc(Add_Months(Current_Date,-1), 'mon') AS TIMESTAMP(0))
```

and `@EndDate` to the last day of the previous month:

```
Cast(Last_Day(Add_Months(Current_Date,-1)) AS TIMESTAMP(0))
```

Today 2018-10-08 this will return:

```
2018-09-01 00:00:00
2018-09-30 00:00:00
```

Of course the Where-condition excludes any rows from the last day of a month.

And the calculation will fail in January when `DATEPART(MM, GETDATE())-1` returns `0` :-)